# First Time Click Function on a li Element is not Fired, but Fires Second Times Onwards

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the page I have a menu button, and after clicking that menu button a drilldown box opens up and there are several options like Copy Record, New Record, save Record etc. The code for that menu button and options inside that menu is as follows:

```
<button type="button" id="s_at_m_2" title="Activities Menu" tabindex="0" data-seq="0">Menu&nbsp;</button>
<ul id="s_at_m_2-menu" class="siebui-appletmenu ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="position: absolute; z-index: 50; top: -79px; left: 130.5px; display: block;" role="menu" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-333">
    <li data-caption="Undo Record                [Ctrl+U]" class="siebui-appletmenu-item  ui-menu-item" role="presentation"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" aria-disabled="true" class="ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled" id="ui-id-317" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Undo Record                [Ctrl+U]</a>

    </li>
    <li data-caption="Delete Record              [Ctrl+D]" class="siebui-appletmenu-item  ui-menu-item" role="presentation"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" aria-disabled="true" class="ui-state-disabled ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-318" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Delete Record              [Ctrl+D]</a>

    </li>
    <li data-caption="" class="siebui-appletmenu-item siebui-appletmenu-separator ui-menu-item" role="presentation"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ui-state-disabled ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-319" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"></a>

    </li>
    <li data-caption="New Record                 [Ctrl+N]" class="siebui-appletmenu-item  ui-menu-item" role="presentation"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" aria-disabled="false" class="ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-320" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">New Record                 [Ctrl+N]</a>

    </li>
    <li data-caption="Copy Record                [Ctrl+B]" class="siebui-appletmenu-item  ui-menu-item" role="presentation"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" aria-disabled="false" class="ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-321" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Copy Record                [Ctrl+B]</a>

    </li>
    <li data-caption="Save Record                [Ctrl+S]" class="siebui-appletmenu-item  ui-menu-item" role="presentation"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" aria-disabled="false" class="ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-322" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Save Record                [Ctrl+S]</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Now whenever I click first time on the Menu->Save Record option after creating a record after the page load, it doesn't fires. But if I do the same operation second time it does save the record. Now if I refresh the page, then same things happen.My question is why its not firing first time? Can anyone help me out?

Thanks.
I am working on siebel open ui platform.
I have used the following code for selecting the Menu->Save Record option in my javascript:

```
$('ul.siebui-appletmenu li[data-caption="Save Record                [Ctrl+S]"]').click(function(e){
 var oMyApplet = theApplication().FindApplet ("Activity List Applet With Navigation");
                    oMyApplet.InvokeMethod('ExecuteQuery');
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    });
```

Whenever user select that Save Record option I need to refresh the above mentioned applet. thats why I added those two lines of code related to the apllet.Its working fine second time onwards, but first time after page load or refresh it doesn't wotk.

Comment: provide a jsfiddle + any js code you may have

Comment: From what I see, your code should work the first time (see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yQ4pV/). So it must be an internal Siebel thing not working... Can you try implementing an alert message to see if your code executes at all the first time? Btw.: I am struggling with openUI menus myself; do you know where Siebel gets the menu entries from? The tools menus seem to not have any effect anymore...